# how to delete a json element?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

How to delete a JSON element in PHP?
That's how I add an element but I have no idea how to delete it

`PHP Code`

```
public function Savefavorite($supplier, $id_shop, $id_supplier, $favActive)
{
    $four = json_decode(Configuration::get('imp_favorite_'.$id_shop), true); // load
    if (!empty($favActive)) { // if 1 exist
        // ??????? DELETE element ???????
    }else { // if 0 no exist ok next
        $four['Suppliers'][$id_supplier]['supplier'] = $supplier;
    }
    Configuration::updateValue('imp_favorite_'.$id_shop, json_encode($four)); //save
}
```

---

`Mysql code`

```
{"Suppliers":{"1":{"supplier":"blablabliblou"},"2":{"supplier":"papapipipupi"}}}
```

Comment: `json_decode`: _"Returns the value encoded in json **in appropriate PHP type**. Values true, false and null are returned as TRUE, FALSE and NULL respectively. NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit."_ -> in your case an array. And you should be able to find enough tutorials on how to work with arrays in PHP.

Comment: thanks and so know how to delete a sample data delete "papapipipupi" ?

Comment: What do you mean by "how to"? What have you tried so far, where **exactly** are you stuck?

Comment: Problem solved thanks to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `unset` for delete, update your `IF..ELSE` as follows

```
if (!empty($favActive)) { // if 1 exist
    // ??????? DELETE element ???????
    unset($four['Suppliers'][$id_supplier]['supplier']);
}else { // if 0 no exist ok next
    $four['Suppliers'][$id_supplier]['supplier'] = $supplier;
}
```

OR

You can delete the entire index using

```
unset($four['Suppliers'][$id_supplier]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
json_decode
```

changes JSON to PHP type (array or stdClass).

```
json_encode
```

changes PHP type (array or stdClass) to JSON. 


In your code you have variable:

```
$four
```

you can delete elements with methods like unset($element).
Example:

```
unset($four['Suppliers'][1]);
```

It will delete your element with id = 1.